# Displaying WebMethod in IIS Logs when calling ASP.NET Web Services

Tags: asp.net, iis, webmethod

Is there an easy pattern to working with ASP.NET Web Services to get the WebMethod (or some other identifier) to show up in the IIS logs?

On our middle/web services/app server tier, most of our ASP.NET Web Service pages (asmx) have multiple WebMethods.  It is nice not having to make multiple pages for each WebMethod, but it kind of falls down when analyzing the IIS logs for usage.

On the front-end/presentation/web server tier, when we add a reference to a Web Service, we just let Visual Studio do its thing when it is adding Web References.

I suspect that the answer is to use Response.AppendToLog within the WebMethod to append the name of the method into the cs-uri-query field. Does anyone have any practical experience using Response.AppendToLog?

Thanks,
Matt